# playing flash file using webkitgtk

Tags: flash, gtk

How can i play flash file using webkitgtk+.

Any tutorial will be helpful.

Comment: Hi all, i got the tutorial link here, check out:http://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/stable/message-board.c.html